# How can i make my texture (or polygon) invisible when i want? (opengl es 1.1)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a square polygon with a texture (opengl es 1.1), and i need that when i want the polygon get's invisible and when i want the polygon turn's visible again.

It's frustrating because seems to be a very easy thing but i can't find any tutorials or examples for do it on google or stackoverflow.

please, can someone give me a sample to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, when the square polygon needs to be invisible, then don't render it...